# DragItemTypes' is not exported from 'react-data-grid'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create dynamic table with option to filter columns using React-Data-Grid and "react-data-grid-addons". I have just imported these 2 in my component and importing grid-add-ons  fails the code with below error. Please assit or if there is any other option to create table with filters

```
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";
import { Toolbar, Data, Filters } from "react-data-grid-addons"; //Writing this only fails the code

./node_modules/react-data-grid-addons/lib/toolbars/GroupedColumnsPanel.js
Attempted import error: 'DragItemTypes' is not exported from 'react-data-grid'.
```

Comment: This was answered here: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/2027
I'm not very sure how to implement the suggestion though. Did you find a way?  @NKapoor

Answer (score -2):

I used Datatable from PrimeReact and it worked smoothly